# Type is not assignable to the interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am having an interface in Typescript which looks like this:

```
interface IProducts {
     id?: number;
     name?: string;
     price?: number;
     photo?: string;
     details?: string;
 };
```

I am trying to create a Context by passing array of JSON values like this:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import { dummyProducts } from '../constants/dummyProducts';
interface IProducts {
     id?: number;
     name?: string;
     price?: number;
     photo?: string;
     details?: string;
 };

export const ProductsContext = createContext<IProducts>({} as IProducts);

const ProductsContextProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {

     const [products] = useState(dummyProducts);

     return (
          <ProductsContext.Provider value={{ products }} >
               { children}
          </ProductsContext.Provider>
     );
}

export default ProductsContextProvider;
```

But I am getting an error here which is:

```
(property) products: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    price: number;
    photo: string;
    details: string;
}[]
Type '{ products: { id: number; name: string; price: number; photo: string; details: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IProducts'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'products' does not exist in type 'IProducts'.ts(2322)
```

This is my interface:

```
interface IProducts {
     id?: number;
     name?: string;
     price?: number;
     photo?: string;
     details?: string;
 };
```

Is there anything wrong with my way of implementation?
I have tried to explicitly typecast the products to any and the interface and it seems to not work.

Edit:
DummyProducts looks like this:

```
export const dummyProducts = [
     {
          id: 1,
          name: "Image 1",
          price: 149,
          photo: "../assets/images/img2.jpg",
          details: "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis eveniet quidem hic ut voluptatum quis, sit dicta quaerat voluptate sequi iste et consequuntur pariatur quo consectetur quod dolor officia veritatis."
     },
     {
          id: 2,
          name: "New Image",
          price: 9,
          photo: "../assets/images/img1.jpg",
          details: "Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis eveniet quidem hic ut voluptatum quis, sit dicta quaerat voluptate sequi iste et consequuntur pariatur quo consectetur quod dolor officia veritatis."
     },
];
```

Comment: how are you defining `dummyProducts`? how does `ProductsContext.Provider` declare products?

Comment: Let me add the details, 
dummyProducts is an Array of JSON objects and ProductsContext.Provider is creating a Context which is accepting the above mentioned Interface

Comment: `useState<any>(dummyProducts);`??

Comment: what is `useState` return type? can you share ProductsContext.Provider code? I believe one issue is you are using `IProducts` instead of `IProducts[]` but that won't solve all your problems

Comment: I have added the whole details @depperm

Comment: `useState(dummyProducts as IProducts[])`?

Comment: You've included the definition of `IProducts` three times in this question; you might want to remove two of them

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvplnN) what you're trying to do?  It seems like you want an array of `IProducts` and not a single `IProducts` object, and when you write `{{products}}` you are doing two different things with those curly braces; the outer ones are a JSX expression marker, and the inner one is an object literal creation... the object `{products}` is not what you want; you want `products` instead.